# Comparing Boolean Vectors

Tags: r, boolean

I have a dataframe with four logical vectors, **v1**, **v2**, **v3**, **v4** that are TRUE or FALSE.  I need to classify each row of the dataframe based on the combination of the boolean vectors (for example, **"None"**, **"v1 only"**, **"v1 and v3"**, **"All"**, etc.).  I would like to do this without taking a subset of the dataframe or nesting ifelse statements.
Any suggestions for the best way to do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I've arrived late at this party.  Still, I might as well share what I've brought!

This works by treating the `FALSE/TRUE` possibilities like bits, and operating on them to assign to each combination of `v1`, `v2`, and `v3` a unique integer between 1 and 8 (much like `chmod` can represent permission bits on `*NIX` systems). The integer is then used as an index to select the appropriate element of a vector of textual descriptors.

(For the demonstration, I've used just three columns, but this approach scales up nicely.)

```
# CONSTRUCT VECTOR OF DESCRIPTIONS
description <- c("None", "v1", "v2", "v1 and v2",
                 "v3", "v1 and v3", "v2 and v3", "All")

# DEFINE DESCRIPTION FUNCTION
getDescription <- function(X) {
    index <- 1 + sum(X*c(1,2,4))
    description[index]
}

# TRY IT OUT ON ALL COMBOS OF v1, v2, and v3
df <- expand.grid(v1=c(FALSE, TRUE),
                  v2=c(FALSE, TRUE),
                  v3=c(FALSE, TRUE))
df$description <- apply(df, 1, getDescription)

# YEP, IT WORKS.
df
#      v1    v2    v3 description
# 1 FALSE FALSE FALSE        None
# 2  TRUE FALSE FALSE          v1
# 3 FALSE  TRUE FALSE          v2
# 4  TRUE  TRUE FALSE   v1 and v2
# 5 FALSE FALSE  TRUE          v3
# 6  TRUE FALSE  TRUE   v1 and v3
# 7 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE   v2 and v3
# 8  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE         All
```

Comment: Thank You! If I add `df$v3 <- TRUE` and then try to run
`df$description <- apply(df, 1, getDescription)` again I get the following error:
**Error in X * c(1, 2, 4) : non-numeric argument to binary operator**  Any ideas why this is happening?  Thanks!

Comment: @BoomShakalaka -- That works just fine for me.  Did you possibly assign `"TRUE"` instead of `TRUE`?  Your error message implies that one column in your `data.frame` is not numeric.  Alternatively, does your `df` have more than just those three columns? If so, you'll need to do `apply(df[c("v1", "v2", "v3")], 1, getDescription)`. Hope that helps.

Comment: There is another column that is not numeric so that was the issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach relying on the fact that `TRUE / FALSE` can be represented as 0s and 1s. You can multiply the booleans by their column index and then paste all the values together. This will tell you which columns had a value of 1 for each row. Here's an example:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(v1 = sample(c(T,F), 10, TRUE),
                  v2 = sample(c(T,F), 10, TRUE),
                  v3 = sample(c(T,F), 10, TRUE),
                  v4 = sample(c(T,F), 10, TRUE)
                  )
#End fake data
#Multiple T/F times the column index
dat <- dat * rep(seq_len(ncol(dat)), each = nrow(dat))
#Paste together in a new column
dat$v5 <- apply(dat, 1, function(x) paste(x, collapse = ""))

> dat
   v1 v2 v3 v4   v5
1   0  0  3  4 0034
2   0  2  0  4 0204
...
```

**Incorporating the helpful comments below and the additional question**

I would create a lookup table using `expand.grid()` and then write the text labels to represent them however you see fit. Here's an example with two columns:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(v1 = sample(c(T,F), 10, TRUE),
                  v2 = sample(c(T,F), 10, TRUE)
       )

#Thanks @Joshua
dat$comp <- as.character(apply(1 * dat, 1, paste, collapse=""))

#Look up table
lookup <- data.frame(comp = apply(expand.grid(0:1, 0:1), 1, paste, collapse = ""),
                     text = c("none", "v1 only", "v2 only", "all"),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

#Use merge to join the look up table to your data. Note the consistent naming of the comp column
> merge(dat, lookup)
   comp    v1    v2    text
1    00 FALSE FALSE    none
2    00 FALSE FALSE    none
3    01 FALSE  TRUE v2 only
....
```

Comment: +1 Nicely done.  Another option also using the 0/1 representation would be to multiply each by a power of 10 and add; this can be done with matrix multiplication, like this `as.matrix(dat) %*% 10^rev(seq_len(ncol(dat))-1)`.  (Or use a power of 2 if you prefer thinking in binary.)

Comment: +1 but I don't see the need for the "column index", since it's defined by the position of the `1`s in the string.  Alternatives would be `apply(1*dat,1,paste,collapse="")` or `do.call(paste, c(1*dat,sep=""))`.

Comment: Thanks.  So building on your answer, I'm thinking of the following: `v1 <- ifelse(v1 == TRUE, 1000, 0)`  `v2 <- ifelse(v1 == TRUE, 100, 0)`  `v3 <- ifelse(v1 == TRUE, 10, 0)`  `v4 <- ifelse(v1 == TRUE, 1, 0)`  `dat$v5 <- sum(v1, v2, v3, v4)`  Should I then create a list of the values to look up the label(e.g. 1111 == "All") or is there a better way?

Comment: @BoomShakalaka - not sure I followed your code there, but think I understand what you need to accomplish. See my updated answer and let me know if I'm close.

Answer (score 2):

Let me throw my hat in the ring as well

```
plyr::adply(dat, 1, function(x) paste(names(Filter(isTRUE, x)), collapse = " and "))

      v1    v2    v3    v4               V1
1   TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE v1 and v2 and v4
2   TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE v1 and v2 and v3
3  FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE               v4
4  FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE v2 and v3 and v4
5   TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE        v1 and v3
6  FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE        v2 and v3
7  FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE               v3
8  FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE        v3 and v4
9  FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE               v2
10  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE v1 and v3 and v4
```

Comment: That hat's worth a +1!  Regular expressions could further refine this, replacing all but the last `and` with a `,` .  Here's something that should work:  `txt <- "v1 and v2 and v3 and v4"`, then `gsub("([[:space:]]and)(?![[:space:]]v[[:digit:]]$)", ",", txt, perl=TRUE)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 set.seed(123)
> dat <- data.frame(v1 = sample(c(T,F), 10, TRUE),
+                   v2 = sample(c(T,F), 10, TRUE),
+                   v3 = sample(c(T,F), 10, TRUE),
+                   v4 = sample(c(T,F), 10, TRUE)
+                   )
> dat
```

The first strategy uses various combination of patterns to index into a vector of character with a default of 1 to index "Other":

```
> dat$bcateg <- c("Other", "v2 only", "v1 and v3", "All")[1+
+ with(dat, 1*(v2 & !v1 &!v3 &!v4))
+ +with(dat, 2*(v1&v3))+
+ with(dat, v1&v2&v3&v4)]
> dat
      v1    v2    v3    v4    bcateg
1   TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE     Other
2  FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE   v2 only
3   TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE     Other
4  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE     Other
5  FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE     Other
6   TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE     Other
7  FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE   v2 only
8  FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE     Other
9  FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE     Other
10  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE v1 and v3
```

The second strategy concatentate the column names of the TRUEs using a separator of ",":

```
> dat$bcateg2 <-paste( c("","v1")[dat[["v1"]]+1 ], c("","v2")[dat[["v2"]]+1 ], c("","v3")[dat[["v3"]]+1 ], c("","v4")[dat[["v4"]]+1 ], sep = ",")
> dat
      v1    v2    v3    v4    bcateg   bcateg2
1   TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE     Other     v1,,,
2  FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE   v2 only     ,v2,,
3   TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE     Other     v1,,,
4  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE     Other       ,,,
5  FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE     Other   ,v2,,v4
6   TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE     Other   v1,,,v4
7  FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE   v2 only     ,v2,,
8  FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE     Other   ,v2,,v4
9  FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE     Other ,v2,v3,v4
10  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE v1 and v3 v1,,v3,v4
```